# When WAWS & WAVM will get out from preview and fully supported

Tags: azure

I think Windows Azure websites (WAWS) & Windows Azure virtual Machine (WAVM) still both are in preview version so does any one know when it will get out from preview version and fully supported?

Thanks.

Comment: They have made no public announcement on this that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arun, the fact is such big product specific decisions are made at corporate level and then made available to public through proper channel i.e. Product website or blog. In forums you are not going to get such very much product specific answers.

So far there is no public announcement made by Windows Azure Product team yet on WAVM, WAWS, WAVNet General Availability (GA).